# Word classes reliant on phonological form?

Tags: phonology, morphology, morphosyntax

**1)** Are there any documented languages in which a certain word class corresponds to a particular phonological structure?

> **A.** CVC(VC) = Noun

In Polish, the word *kot* 'cat' (CVC) corresponds to a noun of the masculine gender. In this sense, the noun-class (Masculine) is encoded phonologically into the word.

If such a phenomenon is prevalent in natural language, could it occur on a higher order, that is:

**2)** As opposed to simply representing a noun class, could a particular phonological form (see **A.**) represent an entire word class?

Comment: The answer hinges on what you mean by "phonological form", "word class", and "=". Do you mean specifically "part of speech" i.e. N, V, A, P, det ...? When you say "encode, correspond, represent, =", do you mean that all and only words of POS X have that property? Do you mean that the words can be described in terms of a prosodic template, described in terms of CV-arrangement, moras or syllables? Assuming the answers are "yes", then I think the answer is "yes, it *could*, but the probability of that ever occurring is diminishingly low". The third point is what makes this improbable.

Comment: Yes. I mean to ask if particular CV-arrangements ex. CV(CV), CVC(CV), VCV(CV) could encode the meaning of a particular "part of speech" into a lexeme.

And when you say "the third point" I am unsure what you are refering to. Can you clarify what "the third point" is? Is that talking about "template"?

Comment: That is, the situation where all and only nouns are trisyllabic, for example.

Comment: In Lushootseed, around 3/4 of the nouns in the language start with the nominalizing prefix _s_-. But Lushootseed is polysynthetic, so it's not entirely clear what the difference between "word" and "clause" actually is.

Comment: Thank you John.

User6726: when I gave that example, I had in mind emphasizing that nouns would be more akin to a string of phones that begin with a consonant and end with a consonant, not however, necessarily limiting the number of syllables, which of course would make said language less probable.

Comment: No, I don't think that's a viable hypothesis. Even in English phonosemantics, where there is clearly a common semantic thread among the phonesthemes, there is no real phonological distinction between verbs and nouns. For example, [consider the `KL-` assonance class](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf), which contains verbs, adjectives, and nouns, but no phonological pattern for their distribution.